# Button in a div both with onclick event - how to trigger only one of both when clicking onto the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, onclick

I'm trying to create a div with a button inside, like this:

```
<div onclick="function()"><input onclick="otherfunction()" type="button"></div>
```

If you click the button both events are triggered, but I want to only trigger the event of the button if you hit it.
I tried to change the z-index of the button to get it over the div but that didn't help.

Is there any posibility to approach that?

Appreciating your answers,
daniel

P.S.: Sorry for any spelling or grammar mistakes this is not my first language.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on what you are trying to achieve here. What should happen when the dig is clicked and what should happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: I assume your div is a big square or something and the button is somehwere inside that square, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Need to stop bubbling with 'stopPropagation'. Try this:

```
<script>
    var test = function() {
        alert(2);
        event.stopPropagation();
    };
</script>

<div onclick="alert(1)"><input onclick="test()" type="button"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to stop propagation use the supplied event object. I am selecting by tag name for illustration purposes, but you supply id's as well. Note that eent.stopPropagation is not supported by IE until version 9:

```
<div)>
    <input type="button" />
</div>    

document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].onclick = function(e) {
    alert('div clicked');
    e.stopPropagation()
    /* do something */
}

document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onclick = function(e) {
    alert('button clicked');
    e.stopPropagation()
    /* do something */
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtxhu17p/)